# В Visual Studio 2015 отсутствует Bitmap

Tags: c#, visual-studio

В Visual Studio 2015 с установленным XNA отсутствует System.Drawing и, следовательно, необходимый мне Bitmap. Что сделать, чтобы я смог использовать использовать Bitmap?

[image]

Comment: `using System.Drawing;` плюс `System.Drawing.dll` в References проекта

Comment: Заработало, огромнейшей спасибо.

Comment: @Igor: Почему не как ответ?

Comment: @VladD не слишком тривиально?

Comment: @Igor: Не-а. Тривиально для того, кто знает, в чём дело.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Namespace вверху должен быть:

```
using System.Drawing;
```

`System.Drawing.Bitmap` - это тип.

Чтобы это пространство имен было доступно, добавьте библиотеку `System.Drawing.dll` в References проекта.